# Is there any word for "re-act?"

Tags: word-request

Not as in "reaction" but as in "to act again."

Example sentence:

> He wanted to re-acted his part of the script.

I tried searching *re-act* on the Internet. But I only got *react*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you can use *re-act* in that sense (it's more the prefix *re* applied to the word *act*), the explicitly defined word is [**reenact**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reenact):

> 1 : to enact (something, such as a law) again
>  2 : to act or
>   perform again
>  3 : to repeat the actions of (an earlier event or
>   incident)

Comment: Reenact would be a good word if he's duplicating a prior performance, e.g, but not if he's acting again and hoping to achieve different results.  It has a flavour of a recreation of something with an air of being faithful to the original

Answer (score 3):

Yes, **re-act** is spelled with a hyphen specifically to avoid confusion with *react* and it means

> To act, do, or perform a second time.

The *Oxford English Dictionary* calls it a "rare" word. Nevertheless, it has an example usage from the *Times* (London) from 2007:

> If you owned both a green carpet and a stripey cat, you could **re-act** classic scenes from *Life On Earth* in your own home.

So, feel free to use it. In context, it should be clear what it means.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [replay](http://improvencyclopedia.org/games/Scene_Replay.html) as in:

> One could limit the scene to 8 lines of dialog per player. Then ask
>   the players to **replay** the scene

Answer (score 0):

No, re-act can't be used like that.

You can use "repeat", as "He wanted to repeat his part of the script." (possibly ambiguous) Another possiblity is "redo".

Or you can use a rephrasing:

> He wanted perform his scene again.
>
> He wanted a second take.  (In the context of video)